# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. Cancel all tasks in a useEffect

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks, undefined, react-hooks

I have seen is a common error and I tried different solutions with no result.

This is my code so far, rarely is working and the fetch is returning a proper movies array but most of the times is sending back an error:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

function Dashboard() {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState([])

   const popularMoviesUrl =
       ".....";

   const fetchMovies = () => {
    fetch(popularMoviesUrl)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(setPopularMovies)
     .then(console.log(popularMovies));
   };

   useEffect(() => {
       fetchMovies();
   }, []);

   const { results } = popularMovies;

      return loading ? (
         <View style={styles.loader}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#dcae1d" animating />
         </View>
   ) : (
      <ScrollView horizontal style={styles.container}>
         {results.map(movie => (
            <View key={movie.id}>
            <Text style={styles.container}>{movie.title}</Text>
            <Image
                style={styles.poster}
                source={{
                    uri: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}`
            }}
          />
        </View>
      ))}
      <Text>thfh</Text>
    </ScrollView>
   );
  }

  export default Dashboard;
```

[image: returned json]

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? All I can think of at the moment is that the component is unmounting before fetchMovies has finished, which would mean you end up trying to setPopularMovies on an unmounted component, but I feel like it's something else. The error message might enlighten! On an unrelated note, I noticed you're destructuring with `const { results } = popularMovies` when popularMovies is actually an array, according to your `useState` at the top.

Comment: the error is undefined is not an object but the yellow warning coming after without any render on the screen says: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

In the image I posted above there is the returned json and what I only need to access is the results array but the weird thing is that sometimes is working and rendering the card properly but most of the time is not

Comment: Can you try logging each step of that fetch, and also change `.then(setPopularMovies)` to `.then(resJson => setPopularMovies(resJson.results))`, then get rid of the `results` variable and just use popularMovies directly. Then at least your popularMovies are a consistent type.

Comment: holy crap that was the issue, this is correct : .then(resJson => setPopularMovies(resJson.results))

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, ha. I'll post it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue referencing the popular movies returned from your fetch. Set your popularMovies state as the `results` property from your fetch rather than the for JSON.

So change:

`.then(setPopularMovies)`

to...

`.then(resJson => setPopularMovies(resJson.results))`

Then remove the results variable and reference popularMovies directly.